# Function is calling itself multiple times

Tags: java

I've written a function which calls itself 3 times more then it should. I call it once in my program, but it executes 4 times in total. Can anyone explain me the problem?

```
 public static String[] MainBooker(Document doc, int counter){
            System.out.println("test");
            Queue<String> mainbooker = new LinkedList<String>();
            Elements span = doc.select("td");
            for(int i = counter+1 ; i < counter +21; i++){
                String inf = span.eq(i).text();
                if(counter%2 == 0 && i%2 == 0){
                    if(!inf.equals("")){
                        if(inf.contains("'"))
                            inf = inf.replaceAll("'", "\'");
                        mainbooker.add(inf);
                    }
                }
                else if(counter%2 != 0 && i%2 != 0){
                    if(!inf.equals("")){
                        if(inf.contains("'"))
                            inf = inf.replaceAll("'", "\'");
                        mainbooker.add(inf);
                    }
                }
            }         

            String[] mainbooker_info = new String[mainbooker.size()];

            int i = 0;
            for (String info : mainbooker) {
                mainbooker_info[i] = info;
                writeToFile(mainbooker_info[i]);
                i++;
            }  
            //Stack:
            //M/V || firstname || middleName || lastName || DoB 
            // Zipcode+ number || street || country || phonenumber || email
            return mainbooker_info;
    }
```

I call it in an if statement:

```
else if(inf.contains("Main booker") ||  inf.contains("Haupt-Bucher") || inf.contains("Hoofdboeker")){  
                String[] result = MainBooker(doc, i);  
                if(!result[2].equals("-")){              
                    informationBasic.add(result[1] +" "+result[2]+ " "+ result[3]);
                }
                else if(result[2].equals("-")){
                    informationBasic.add(result[1] + " "+ result[3]);
                }
                mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(MainBooker(doc, i)));
            }
```

Comment: problems with recursion.... lets see

Comment: You should adhere the conventions and set function names from lowercase

Comment: ok, from the context i can not make out what your intentions are, could you aadd that? Ie 'I want to to run x times '

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean. Which function is calling itself, and what exactly do you mean by this? In the code that you posted, there is no function that is calling itself.

Comment: When I add a System.out.println("test") above Queue<String> mainBooker = new LinkedList<String>(); it wil print test 4 times, even if i've called MainBooker() just once in my whole program.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the calling code... which you haven't posted yet.

Comment: i am failing to see a 'print("test")' statement...

Comment: see update, my bad

Comment: The method *isn't* calling itself at all - your *other* method calls it 4 times. It's being called multiple times because... you call it multiple times.

Comment: I agree, but there should be an extra call within the function. I've changed like @Chinmay jain said and it still calls 2 times.

Comment: @wolteeer You missed one: `mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(MainBooker(doc, i)));`.

Comment: Also, please include the old code in the question as well as the edited code (otherwise the question won't make sense to future readers) and include an explanation of why you expected the old code to work (so that it's more useful to future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
else if(inf.contains("Main booker") ||  inf.contains("Haupt-Bucher") || inf.contains("Hoofdboeker")){  
            if(!MainBooker(doc, i)[2].equals("-")){              
                informationBasic.add(MainBooker(doc, i)[1] +" "+MainBooker(doc, i)[2]+ " "+ MainBooker(doc, i)[3]);
            }
            else if(MainBooker(doc, i)[2].equals("-")){
                informationBasic.add(MainBooker(doc, i)[1] + " "+ MainBooker(doc, i)[3]);
            }
            mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(MainBooker(doc, i)));
        }
```

MainBooker has been call multiple times. Try this instead:

```
else if(inf.contains("Main booker") ||  inf.contains("Haupt-Bucher") || inf.contains("Hoofdboeker")){
String[] result = MainBooker(doc, i);  
if(!result[2].equals("-")){              
    informationBasic.add(result[1] +" "+result[2]+ " "+ result[3]);
}
else if(result[2].equals("-")){
    informationBasic.add(result[1] + " "+ result[3]);
}
mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(result));}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it now prints it twice instead of four times.

Comment: Can you upload the updated code?

Comment: I have update, thanks for your response

Comment: Instead of mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(MainBooker(doc, i)));, use this: mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(result));

Comment: @wolteeer Chinmayjain is correct - plz replace `mainbooker.addAll(Arrays.asList(MainBooker(doc, i)));` with the corresponding line shown in this answer.